# Como convertir array asociativo a array normal en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Explico un poco el código para que que quede todo claro, primero obtengo un array con el metodo  query builder de laravel, una vez obtengo el array necesito recorrer mediante un bucle todos sus elementos para extraerlos y meterlos en una variable tipo string, he intentado cambiar el tipo de array asociativo a array normal mediante ->toArray() pero sin resultado, el error que me salta es el siguiente:**Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string**, me dice que no puedo convertirlo a string, imagino que sera por que es un array asociativo,  ya que he probado con array normales y funciona correctamente.

Array asociativo:

```
 $consulta = DB::table('partes_trabajo')

 ->select(
           'partes_trabajo.user_id as Usuario: ',
           DB::raw('SUM(desplazamiento) as Km'),
           DB::raw('SUM(peaje) as Peaje'),
           DB::raw('SUM(aparcamiento) as Aparcamiento'),
           DB::raw('SUM(otros_gastos) as Otros_gastos'),

                   )

  ->whereIn('user_id',$usuarios)
  ->whereBetween('fecha', [$fechaD, $fechaH])
  ->groupBy('user_id')
  ->get();
```

Bucle

```
 $rows="";
 $consultab = $consulta->toArray();
 $count = count($consultab);



 for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){   

        $usuario = $consultab[$i];


           $rows =  $rows.$usuario . "\n"; \\Aqui se genera el problema que viene del array asociativo





 }
```

Comment: Los arrays no se convierten... se leen y si es preciso se almacena el resultado de esa lectura en una variable. Quizá ni siquiera haga falta convertir el objeto con `toArray`, sino leerlo y sacar de él la información que necesites. No sé por qué quieres liarte convirtiéndolo en array ¿?

Comment: SI no lo combierto con toArray me pasa lo mismo pero como dije arriba con un array normal no me pasa,con el normal me funciona perfectamente

Comment: No hay arrays normales y arrays anormales. La clave es que conozcas la estructura del objeto para que luego sepas cómo tienes que leerlo. A veces hay arrays anidados a varios niveles y tienes que conocer la estructura para saber por ejemplo si en una determinada clave del objeto hay un array, un json, una cadena, etc y según eso tendrías que leer esa clave de una forma o de otra. Para ver la estructura del objeto puedes hacer un `var_dump`. Creo que te estás liando demasiado pensando que la solución es convertir el objeto a array.   Eso no te resuelve nada, tienes que conocer la estructura.

Comment: Si quieres muestra un `var_dump($consulta);`  y di qué datos quieres leer y te diremos cómo hacerlo. No tienes por qué liarte convirtiéndolo a array.

Comment: Si realizo el vardump a $consulta me devuelve un objeto, y cuando lo casteo a ->toArray me devuelve claramente un  array de las dos maneras no me hace el bucle y en cambio con array normal si por eso mi primer impulso fue pasar de objeto a  array, de todos modos no se por donde coger el asunto...

Comment: var dump array: array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#424 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(7) ["Km"]=> float(97.22) ["Peaje"]=> float(143) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(8.2) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(76.7) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#442 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(10) ["Km"]=> float(54.15) ["Peaje"]=> float(0) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(3.4) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(70) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#425 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(17) ["Km"]=> float(45.88) ["Peaje"]=> float(12.5) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(0) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(0) } }

Comment: var dump objetc: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#426 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#424 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(7) ["Km"]=> float(97.22) ["Peaje"]=> float(143) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(8.2) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(76.7) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#442 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(10) ["Km"]=> float(54.15) ["Peaje"]=> float(0) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(3.4) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(70) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#425 (5) { ["Usuario: "]=> int(17) ["Km"]=> float(45.88) ["Peaje"]=> float(12.5) ["Aparcamiento"]=> float(0) ["Otros_gastos"]=> float(0) } } }

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105003/discussion-between-david-robles-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo de cómo es que quieres armar el resultado final.

Comment: Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403049/errorexception-array-to-string-conversion) a tu pregunta? @A.Cedano que te parece la respuesta de la publicación? Me refiero a la teoría explicada agradecería tu observacion

Comment: @BetaM el principal problema aquí es la dificultad de OP para explicar qué es lo que realmente quiere o necesita. Por lo dicho en el chat parece que quiere leer un objeto anidado. La respuesta dada me parece que se aleja del problema real. Ya comenté a OP que quizá ni siquiera necesite convertir el objeto a array. En la respuesta se propone otra manipulación del dato ya manipulado (dos conversiones/manipulaciones sin necesidad). Es lo que pasa cuando de entrada no tienes claro lo que quieres hacer, que luego reflejas esa confusión mareando los datos de un lado para otro.

Comment: Entiendo @A.Cedano de hecho como no estaba del todo seguro por eso no la voté para cierre, deja elimino el comentario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza array_values(). https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-values.php

```
$consultab = $consulta->toArray();
$consultab = array_values($consultab);
```

con eso obtienes los valores y desechas los indices, obteniendo un array con nuevos indices numericos

Comment: no eso no me funciona, el problema lo tengo en $rows que no deja que un objeto de tipo stdclass sea string, por lo tanto primero tendria que sacar mediante un bucle los elementos del objeto y meteterlos en un array, o eso creo yo...

Comment: Mediante este bucle he conseguido convertir el array tipo objeto stdclass a array normal pero en el bucle for ahora me salta que el array no puede convertirse a string....
     $nuevo_arreglo = array();
     $arreglo = json_decode(json_encode($consulta), true);  

     foreach( $arreglo as $indice=>$valor )
     {
     
        $nuevo_arreglo[] = $valor;

       
     
     } 
      
     /

Comment: He dado un voto negativo a tu respuesta. ¿Por qué no se trabaja directamente sobre `$consultab`? ¿Por qué hay que marear los datos de esta manera, primero aplicando `toArray()` y luego aplicando `array_values()`? Aunque esto resolviera el problema, tantas manipulaciones sin necesidad sobrecargan el código.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu voto :D es un post viejo, en mi opinión no necesita ser revivido ya que ha estas alturas seguramente el usuario resolvió su duda, aun asi, te invito a aportar con tu granito de arena y nos ilumines con un mejor método, probablemente he errado pero estoy abierto a aprender algo nuevo.