# Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

Buenas me tope con este error al momento de ejecutar esta sentencia al querer guardar, este es mi codigo:

```
$this->saldo = DB::select("select ifnull(saldo,0) saldo FROM aportes where id=(select max(id) from aportes where id_personal=".$this->id_personal." and id_concepto_pago=".$this->id_concepto_pago.")");
      echo $this->saldo;
```

de alli va el create, pero me aparece:
ErrorException Array to string conversion

Si ejecuto
echo $this->saldo[0];
me da el siguiente error:

Error:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

esto me da cuando le doy echo en $this->saldo, porque quería ver que traia la variable.
PD. no estoy trabajando con requests ya que estoy usando livewire.
PD2. mi query en mi BD me trae el valor que necesito.

Comment: pero hice el intento de tirarlo saldo[0] pero me da este error: Error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: obtiene esto: array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1440 ▼
    +"saldo": "100.00"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

El método `select` que estás usando perteneciente al [facade `DB`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries) te retornará:

- Un array de resultados
- Cada resultado dentro del array será un objeto de la clase [stdClass](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-a-select-query)
- Tal como nos indica la propia doc. la manera de acceder a los elementos del array será a través de una sintaxis como la siguiente:

  ```
  foreach ($his->algo as $otro) {
      $otro->clave;
  }
  ```

Te anexo un ejemplo que hice para tratar de ejemplificar mejor esto:

1. Asumamos que la consulta te estuviera retornando un array de objetos como la siguiente:

   ```
   $nuevoObjeto = array(
           (object)array("clave1" => 1, "clave2" => 2),
           (object)array("clave1" => 3, "clave2" => 4)
       );
   ```
2. Si la hacemos un `var_dump()` a `$nuevoObjeto` veremos que la salida indica precisamente lo que la doc. de Laravel nos indica un array de objetos de la clase `stdClass` mira:

   ```
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
        ["clave1"]=>
        int(1)
        ["clave2"]=>
        int(2)
      }
      [1]=>
      object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
        ["clave1"]=>
        int(3)
        ["clave2"]=>
        int(4)
      }
    }
   ```
3. Ahora si, tal cual nos propone la doc. podemos acceder a estos valores de la siguiente forma:

   ```
    foreach ($nuevoObjeto as $otro) {
       echo $otro->clave1;
    }
   ```

Dando como salida:

```
1
3
```

**Nota**

Si la salida por ejemplo fuera un array de solo un objeto tienes 2 opciones:

- Iterar como ya he explicado
- Indicar el índice para recuperar el valor deseado

**Ejemplo**

```
$nuevoObjeto = array(
        (object)array("clave1" => 1, "clave2" => 2)
    );
    
var_dump($nuevoObjeto);
    
echo $nuevoObjeto[0]->clave1;
```

Dando como salida:

> 1

**Referencias**

- [Documentación sobre `stdClass`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)
- [mas sobre stdClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19272011/how-to-convert-an-array-into-an-object-using-stdclass) *aclarando que este enlace no es base de esta respuesta* pero puede ampliar mas sobre `stdClass` de lo que expone la doc. de PHP